# Why does the "All time" reviewed post counter decrease?

Tags: support, review

Today, I reviewed low quality posts. I started with 520 reviewed posts, and I ended up with 712 reviewed posts.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I checked after few hours, and the counter is now lower.

[image: screenshot]

Why does that happens?

I noticed it happening twice, already. When I checked before, the reviewed posts were higher than 520.

I reviewed more low quality posts. When I stopped, the number of reviewed posts was 1194; I checked after one hour, and the number of reviewed posts went to 1150.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wild guess: deleted posts don't count?

Comment: The first time the difference was too much, to just be deleted posts. It was about 50-70 posts, or more.